# Mixing char and int up with concat

Tags: c

When I try to compile this code in Arduino IDE I get an error: "request for member 'concat' in 'content', which is of non-class type 'char'"

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
//Schematic: irled on pin 13 with a resistor that simple
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
char content = ' ';
char character;

// Raw codes for buttons of Samsung remote control BN5900706A
unsigned int buttonPower[68] = {4500, 4450, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1650, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550, 600, 550,550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1650, 600};

unsigned int buttonRecord[68] = {4450, 4450, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600,550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 550, 1700, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 550, 600, 1650, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600,1650, 550, 600, 550, 1700, 550, 1650, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550};

unsigned int buttonPlay[68] = {4500, 4450, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550,550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 550,600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600,550, 600, 1650, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600};

unsigned int buttonStop[68] = {4500, 4450, 550, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 550, 600, 500, 600, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 1650, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 1700, 550, 1650, 600, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600,550, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 600};
// End of codes for buttons of Samsung BN5900706A

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {

while(Serial.available()) {
      character = Serial.read();
      content.concat(character);
//    content+=character;
  }

if (content !=' ') {

  if(content=='buttonPower') {delay(100);irsend.sendRaw(buttonPower,68,38);delay(100);Serial.println("buttonPower sent.");};
  if(content=='buttonPlay') {delay(100);irsend.sendRaw(buttonProgramDown,68,38);delay(100);Serial.println("buttonPlaysent.");}
  else {irsend.sendRaw(buttonRecord,68,38);};
  Serial.println(content);
  content=' ';
  }

delay(1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The following part doesn't actually solve the problem:

You can convert the `int` returned by the `Serial.read()`-function into a `byte` like this:

```
character = byte(Serial.read());
```

**EDIT:** Also, it seems that you would like to contain multiple characters in the variable `content`. A `byte` can only contain one ASCII character. In order to store multiple characters, I would use the `String`-type:

```
String content = " ";
```

Additionally, you are trying to define bytes instead of Strings in the following comparisons:

```
content !=' '
content=='buttonPower'
content=='buttonPlay'
```

They should be changed to:

```
content !=" "
content=="buttonPower"
content=="buttonPlay"
```

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Now I don't get any error messages. But the if-clauses don't work anyway. Instead the else-clause is executed. I have absolutely no clue why.

Comment: @NazimKenan Try print content before the buttonifs, to see what is actually given by the remote.

Comment: I would suggest trying to add spaces to all the conditions like so: " buttonPower",  etc. The prefixing space isn't actually needed, and removing it entirely might make your code a bit clearer, as Strings can also be empty.